# Can Visual Studio 2012 Load testing capture performance counters of Linux server and Oracle data base?

Tags: linux, oracle, visual-studio-2012, performance-testing, load-testing

I need to test Oracle ERP system module which runs on Linux server and uses oracle as a database. I have some past experience with web performance and load testing however I am not sure whether Visual Studio 2012 is capable of capturing server side performance counters when it comes to linux platform and oracle data base profiling and tracing counters. so following are my questions :

1. Can I capture server specific counters using vs 2012 ?
2. Is VS 2012 capable of oracle sql tracing and profiling ? if Yes than How to set counters for oracle sql tracing and profiling ?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it doesn't... Created shell scripts and Oracle DBA ascripts to capture the performance counters....

Answer (score 0):

It can be done but it is hard work. I have been told of the following method, but do not have any details.

The basic idea is to make the Unix counters visible as Windows Performance counters. Then the Visual Studio Load Test (also `Perfmon`) can access those counters just like any other sets of counters. To do this either write your own code or use standard utilities to monitor data within the Unix system and forward it to your code running in a Windows computer. SNMP provides visibility to counters on Unix and so that may be a suitable means of passing the data to the Windows. On the Windows computer your code then transforms the data to your performance counters in Windows.

Comment: Yes as you mentioned its a hard work... the basic steps involved to achieve the object are 
Step 1 : capture performance counters (write shell script or use any monitoring tools)
Step 2 : Pass these counters to Test Agents (This can be done offline i.e. save results in file and than import this file and mount it on test results for analysis)

Comment: @MithunGanatra No, you have misunderstood this answer. I outlined a way of getting the Unix performance data while the load test is running. So that data can be saved into the Load Test Database while the test is running, just like any other performance counter from an agent or from the system under test.